# Can you explain what this typecast do?

Tags: c++

Given a string in terms of `const char*`

```cpp
const char *str = "Hello, World!\n";
```

`std::cout << *str;` will give `H`, but `std::cout << *(char (*)[12])str;` will give the complete string `Hello, World!`.

I can understand that this cast takes 12 of some kind of data, but what does the `(*)` here mean?

Comment: You can use http://cdecl.org to test this sort of thing.

Comment: In this case, it is just obfuscation. There's no need for this cast, because `std::cout << str;` gives the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but what does the (*) here mean?

The difference between `char [12]` and `char (*)[12]` is that former is an array of 12 char while the latter is a pointer to an array of 12 char.

Note that when you cast array (such as a string literal) to a pointer type, it will first decay to a pointer to first element of the array. The pointer to first element of an array is not pointer-interconvertible with pointer to the array itself. Thus, indirecting through the reinterpreted pointer results in undefined behaviour.

P.S. Avoid using C-style cast operator and instead prefer using static_cast, reinterpret_cast and const_cast. Avoid casting string literals to non-const since that can easily lead to accidentally modifying the string literal which results in undefined behaviour.

P.P.S. To print the whole string, use `std::cout << str;`. No cast is needed here.

> What about char * [12]?

That is an array of 12 pointers to char.

Comment: What's the betting the author of that cast thought they were static casting? They hit the UB double of reinterpret + const cast

Comment: @Caleth I wouldn't assume the author necessarily even thought that far. 12 doesn't even match the length of the array.

Comment: "*The pointer to first element of an array is not pointer-interconvertible with pointer to the array itself*" - sure, it is. The address of the array itself, and the address of its first element, are guanateed to be the same address. However, in this example, `"Hello, World!\n"` is not a `char[12]`, it is a `const char[16]` instead. Casting to the wrong type is UB.